# Hi, I have a problem with a django app. I want do make personalized pages for users with this url: url/user/id. But something doesn't work

Tags: python, django

I'm quite new in the programming world and that's my firs real project. Usually I solve my problems just sitting and thinking till my brain burns. But this time I'm really stacked. Maybe is easy but I really didn't find solutions

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('profilo/<int:my_id>/', views.profilo, name='profilo')
]
```

**views.py**

```
def profilo(request, my_id):
    users = User.objects.get(id=my_id)
    contex = {
        "user": users
    }
    return render(request, 'profilo/profilo.html', contex)
```

**base.html**

```
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Django Boyz blog</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page-header">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
                <p class="top-menu">Ciao {{ user.username }} <small>(<a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log out</a>)</small></p>
                
                <a href="{% url 'profilo' User.id %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
              
                {% if user.is_superuser %}
                    <a href="{% url 'numeroposts' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></span></a>

                {% endif %}
            {% else %}
                <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></a>
            {% endif %}
            <h1><a href="/">Django Boyz Blog</a></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    {% block content %}
                    {% endblock %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The error is this: NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'profilo' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profilo/(?P<my_id>[0-9]+)/$']
Thanks

Comment: Does the error specify where the error is? If so, please tell

Comment: What’s the URL you’re visiting the produces this error?

Comment: Isn't it because of the capital U in `User.id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
<a href="{% url 'profilo' User.id %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
```

The u should be small in `User.id`:

```
<a href="{% url 'profilo' user.id %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
```